# How can a class extend and implement other classes and interfaces at the same time?

Tags: java

I don't get how can I write a sub class which will extend a superclass and a couple of interfaces at the same time.

Comment: This is best answered by reading an intro to Java book, section on classes and interfaces.

Comment: Try reading up on this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Maybe you should read about how classes and interfaces are used, because you're mixing terminology. You can implement interfaces in your class, not extend them. You can only extend an interfaces by another interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class can only extend one superclass, but can implement multiple interfaces, which is done by separating them by a comma, like so:

```
public class MyClass extends AnotherClass implements AnInterface, AnotherInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending a class is simple: unless the class you are extending is abstract, your class does not even need to do anything apart from providing a suitable constructor.

Implementing an interface or extending an abstract class, on the other hand, is simply a promise to implement a specific set of methods, as declared in the corresponding abstract class and/or the interface. Again, all your class needs to do is providing *some* implementation for these methods.

Of course, the implementations need to make sense in the overall scheme of your design, but technically they just need to be there in order for the code to compile.